# How to stop the find command after first match?

Tags: find

Is there a way to force the `find` command to stop right after finding the first match?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

With GNU or FreeBSD `find`, you can use the `-quit` predicate:

```
find . ... -print -quit
```

The NetBSD `find` equivalent:

```
find . ... -print -exit
```

If all you do is printing the name, and assuming the filenames don't contain newline characters, you could do:

```
find . ... -print | head -n 1
```

That will not stop `find` after the first match, but possibly, depending on timing and buffering upon the second match or (much) later. Basically, `find` will be terminated with a SIGPIPE when it tries to output something while `head` is already gone because it has already read and displayed the first line of input.

Note that not all shells will wait for that `find` command after `head` has returned. The Bourne shell and AT&T implementations of `ksh` (when non-interactive) and `yash` (only if that pipeline is the last command in a script) would not, leaving it running in background. If you'd rather see that behaviour in any shell, you could always change the above to:

```
(find . ... -print &) | head -n 1
```

If you're doing more than printing the paths of the found files, you could try this approach:

```
find . ... -exec sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$1"; kill -s PIPE "$PPID"' sh {} \;
```

(replace `printf` with whatever you would be doing with that file).

That has the side effect of `find` returning an exit status reflecting the fact that it was killed though.

We're sending the SIGPIPE signal instead of the default SIGTERM to avoid the message that some shells display when parts of a pipe line are killed with a signal. They generally don't do it for deaths by SIGPIPE, as those are naturally happening (like in `find | head` above...).

Comment: In case anybody needs to test whether any file matches the predicates, stopping as soon as one is found, in Bash and GNU Find you can do: `if [[ $(find ... -print -quit) ]]; then ...` It just tests whether find printed anything at all.

Comment: @Tobia Better to put the `$(…)` part in quotes in case you are using just the single brackets (`[ … ]`).

Comment: @phk Except I'm not using the single brackets (because they are horrible) so I don't need to use quotes.

Comment: @Tobia, `[` is a standard command. It's not so much that command that is horrible but the way Bourne-like shells parse command lines. `[[...]]` is a ksh construct that has issues of its own in various shells. For instance, until recently `[[ $(...) ]]` wouldn't work in `zsh` (you needed `[[ -n $(...) ]]`). Except in `zsh`, you need quotes in `[[ $a = $b ]]`, the `[[ =~ ]]` has incompatible differences between implementations and even between versions for bash and several bugs in some. Personally, I prefer `[`.

Comment: what is `...`? .

Comment: When using `-exec` is the answer by Noam placing `-quit` after `\;` not a much easier and better way?

Comment: @Kvothe, the approach with `kill -s PIPE` was shown mainly for `find` implementations that don't support those non-standard `-exit` or `-quit`. Beware however that if you do `find ... -exec cmd {} ';' -quit`, `-quit` will only be run if `cmd` succeeds. You'd need `find ... '(' -exec cmd {} ';' -o -true ')' -quit` to run `cmd` only once regardless of whether it succeeds or not (`-true` being another GNU extension).

Answer (score 21):

```
find . -name something -print -quit
```

Terminates find after the first match after printing it.

Terminate find after a specific amount of matches and print results:

```
find . -name something -print | head -n 5
```

Surprisingly enough - head now terminates string after 5 matches, though I do not know how or why.

It is very easy to test. Just let find search *a* on root which would result thousands, maybe even more matches while taking at least a minute or more.
But when piped into "head" "find" will terminate after the specified amount of **lines** defined in head (default head shows 10, use "head -n" to specify lines).

Note that this will terminate after "head -n" reaches the specified newline character count and therefore any match that contains multiple newline characters will count accordingly.

Comment: I have also observed this 'program terminates after head is done with its output' phenomenon, but not consistently across shells.   I think this merits its own question - fortunately for bash the answer is already at StackOverflow's [Bash: Head & Tail behavior with bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26462868/527489).  That gives enough information for me to conclude that whether the program terminates or continues to execute in the background depends on its response to SIGPIPE - killing is the default.

Comment: I meant 'across *programs*/shells', but apparently unix.stackexchange.com would prefer that I log this as a second comment rather than letting me edit my first comment (this is a stackexchange, site-specific policy decision).  Also, I now see that @Ruste commented to this effect at the top, which did not help me initially since I went straight to answers...

Answer (score 7):

When running find with `-exec` use `-quit` after the `\;`, otherwise the command execution will be skipped. For example:

```
find -name "myfile*" -exec echo "Found {} and Quit" \; -quit
Found ./myfile1 and Quit
```

But when using -quit **before** -exec:

```
find -name "myfile*" -quit -exec echo "Found {} and Quit" \;
# Nothing was executed
```

Answer (score 2):

For entertainment purposes, here's a lazy find generator in Bash. This example generates a ring over the files in the current directory. Read however many you want then `kill %+` (maybe just 1)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
unset -v files n
trap 'kill "$x_PID"' EXIT

coproc x while :; do
    find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c "$(</dev/fd/3)" _ {} +
done 4<&0 <<\EOF 3<&0 <&4-
for x; do
    read -r _
    printf '%s\0' "$x"
done
EOF

while
    echo >&${x[1]}
    IFS= read -rd '' -u "$x" 'files[n++]'
do
    printf '%q ' "${files[@]}"
    echo
    sleep .2
done
```

Answer (score 2):

grep also returns if used with the flag `-m`, so with

```
find stuff | grep -m1 .
```

it will return after the first line printed by find.

The difference between this and `find stuff -print -quit | head -1` is that if the search is fast enough grep might not be able to stop the process in time (doesn't really matter though), while if the search is long it will spare find to print a lot of not needed lines.

this instead works with busybox find, although since busybox grep also has `-m` it is not really needed

```
find /tmp/stuff -exec "sh" "-c" "eval 'echo {}; { kill \$PPID; }'" \;
```

this will spit out a message about the find process having received the (usually) sigterm signal, but this output belongs to the running shell, not the find command so it does not mess with command output, meaning pipes or redirects will output just the line matched by find.

Answer (score 0):

```
find  path -name something | awk 'NR == 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I Didn't catch a bit of the ring stuff answer, so i re-implemented like this:
takes 3 arguments
1st: working directory
2nd: extension to find
3rt: number of results to show

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -z "${1}" ]
then
    CWD="$(pwd)"
else
    CWD="${1}"
fi

if [ -z "${2}" ]
then
    EXT="wma"
else
    EXT="${2}"
fi

if [ -z "${3}" ]
then
    MAX=1
else
    MAX="${3}"
fi

TMPFILE=$(tempfile -p mtfind-)
find ${CWD} -iname "*.${EXT}" -type f 2>/dev/null 1>${TMPFILE} &
PID=$!
WCL=0
CONDITION=1
while [ ${CONDITION}  ]
do
    WCL=$(wc -l ${TMPFILE} | cut -d " " -f1)    
    CONDITION=$(echo "${WCL}<${MAX}"| bc -l)
    if [ -d "/proc/${PID}" ]; then
        echo -ne "."
    else
        echo "find ended"
        head -n${MAX} "${TMPFILE}"
        rm -f ${TMPFILE}
        exit
    fi
    sleep .02
done
kill -9 ${PID} 
head -n${MAX} "${TMPFILE}"
rm -f ${TMPFILE}
```