# How can I test for the .RAW file extension?

Tags: shell, shell-script, filenames, wildcards

I'm trying to set up an `sh` script that will run every 30 minutes. During each run, I want to check a directory for the presence of at least one .RAW file. Upon finding that file extension, I will have other code to execute, but right now I'm having trouble figuring out the correct if statement to use.

I know this code example isn't the most ideal way to do it, but here's the code I tried which is obviously wrong:

```
cd ./dir/
if [ ! -f "*.RAW"]; then
  echo "No files!"
else
  echo "Yes files!"
fi
```

How can I correctly test for the presence of the .RAW extension?

Comment: Related (though `bash` specific): [Test if there are files matching a pattern in bash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79301)

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
files=(*.RAW(DN))
if (($#files)); then
  echo Yes
else
  echo No
fi
```

If you're only interested in *regular* files (or symlinks to regular files) as your `-f` implies, that would be:

```
file=(*.RAW(ND-.))
```

instead.

POSIXly:

```
has_regfiles_by_extension() {
  for ext do
    for file in .*."$ext" ."$ext" *."$ext"; do
      [ -f "$file" ] && return
    done
    return 1
  done
}

if has_regfiles_by_extension RAW raw; then
  echo YES
else
  echo NO
fi
```

If you wanted to use `ls` instead, you could do:

```
if ls -Aq | grep -q '\.RAW$'; then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```

One of the benefits is that if the directory is not readable, you'll get an error message (instead of being silently ignored in the case of shell globs).

Comment: What is zsh? I apologize, I'm not very knowledgeable with shell scripting yet. I'm just using sh, and I'm getting syntax errors for unexpected '(' in the "files=(*.RAW(ND-.))" line.

Comment: @Alex26, `zsh` is one of the most advanced Unix shells. By POSIXly, I mean compatible with the standard `sh` syntax as [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xcu.html). Many shell implementations understand that syntax (`dash`, `bash`, `ksh`, `yash`, `zsh` in `sh` emulation...) and all modern Unix-like operating sytems have a command called `sh` (typically, one of the above) that can interpret it which makes it for the most portable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your example answer is almost correct. First, you need to separate the testing string `".RAW"` from the closing `]`:

```
if [ ! -f "*.RAW" ];
```

You can do shell globbing in this context by taking the asterisk outside of the quotes. So the finished command would be:

```
if [ ! -f *".RAW" ];
```

---

However, this approach isn't so useful if you want to **use** the `.RAW` files. If that's the case, I'd compare the extension of each file in the directory like so:

```
for file in "test/"*; do
    if [ "${file##*.}" = "RAW" ]; then
        echo "Found raw file"
    fi
done
```

The Bash syntax ${var##*.} is a part of the clever shell parameter expansion you can do. You can find more information on the [GNU website](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: `[ ! -f *".RAW" ]` only ever makes for a valid `test`/`[` expression in the case there is 0 or 1 RAW file in the current directory.

Comment: Note that `${var##*.}` is not `bash` specific. It's standard `sh` syntax (actually introduced by `ksh`).

Comment: My bad. I remember reading the `*"ext"` syntax on a different SE question, but I might've used it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, although I haven't been able to get some of these to work.

I did, however, successfully implement code I found in an answer to another question! (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87476)

```
export DIR=./folder
if ls ${DIR}/*.RAW &>/dev/null
then
  echo "Yes!"
else
  echo "No!"
fi
```

Comment: Note that `export` is to export a shell variable to the environment of all the commands it runs. It makes little sense here as none of the commands you run make use of that environment variable.

Comment: Note that `&>` is not standard `sh` syntax. It's only recognised by `bash` (the shell where it originated where other shells like csh, tcsh or zsh have `>&` instead)  and recent versions of `zsh`.

Comment: Leaving a variable unquoted like that has a very special meaning. It's like invoking a split+glob operator. It doesn't make sense here.

Comment: `ls` will return _false_ if it fails to list any of the file or directories it is passed as argument. For instance, it will return false if `${DIR}/*.RAW` has no match (because in that case `${DIR}/*.RAW` expands to `./folder/*.RAW` and there won't be any file by that name. Or it could return false, because for instance one of the `.RAW` files passed to `ls` from the expansion (by the shell) of `${DIR}/*.RAW` is a directory which you don't have read access to.

Comment: Note that by default, shells exclude files whose name starts with `.` from the expansion of globs like `*.RAW`, so this approach may fail to detect `RAW` files. Hence the `(D)` zsh glob qualifier in my answer (there's no equivalent in standard `sh` syntax unfortunately).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I successfully removed `export` from my code and switched the `&>` to `>&`. However, I'm confused as to which unquoted variable you are referring to.

Comment: I also want to give a bit more info: This file and my python script will be set up on a computer that will be used for the sole purpose of retrieving any recent `App*.RAW`, `EXO*.RAW`, and `GPS*.RAW` files (we know all the naming conventions of all files that will be returned) and placing those into the subfolder I specify in code. I just want this code to call a python script to analyze the files if and only if there were new files to retrieve. That said, any changes I have tried to make to `${DIR}/*.RAW` are giving me the wrong results.

Comment: The `ls ${DIR}/*.RAW` should be `ls -d -- "$DIR"/*.RAW`. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) and all the links to other questions referenced in there for details.

Answer (score -1):

### Two Bourne Shell Solutions

With the Bourne shell (which doesn't support arrays, or shell options like *nullglob* or *failglob*) you have to work around the fact that a non-zero exit status or the glob itself will be returned if a glob isn't found. For example:

```
if [ -n "`ls *.RAW 2> /dev/null`" ]; then
    echo "At least one RAW file found!"
else
    echo "No RAW files found."
fi
```

In general, one shouldn't rely on the output of the *ls* command, but this is sufficient for your use case and works around the limitations of the Bourne shell. If you really want to use only shell built-ins, you have to use assignment and explicitly test for the glob itself as an error condition. For example:

```
files=*.RAW
if [ "$files" = "*.RAW" ]; then
    echo "No RAW files found."
else
    echo "At least one RAW file found!"
fi
```

Comment: No. `[[ *.RAW =~ RAW ]]` is a test for wether the `*.RAW` string is matched by the `RAW` regular expression (which obviously it is)

Comment: `[ -n "$(ls *.RAW 2> /dev/null)" ]` is wrong. First, there's the problem of file names starting with `-`. Then, if ommits hidden files. Also, it will fail if the only non-hidden `RAW` file in the current directory is of type directory (or symlink to directory) and is empty (but for hidden files) or not readable.

Comment: Also note that the Bourne shell never supported the `$(...)` syntax. More than likely, the OP is not using the Bourne shell as that shell is no longer in use nowadays (except maybe on Solaris 10 and before if you're using /bin/sh instead of the standard sh in /usr/xpg4/bin).

Comment: The `files=*.RAW; [ "$files" = "*.RAW" ]` solution is also plain wrong. It just tests wether `*.RAW` is the same string as `*.RAW`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You are incorrect. `files=*.RAW; [ "$files" = "*.RAW" ]` works because of the way globbing works when no matches are found. In the absence of *nullglob* or *failglob*, when a glob can't be expanded, the shell returns the original glob pattern (in this case, the string `*.RAW`), which is indeed what the match is looking for.

Comment: In `files=*.RAW`, there's no globbing because you're assigning to a scalar variable. (see `echo "$files"`). There would have been globbing with `files=(*.RAW)` (ksh93/zsh/bash syntax). But even then `[ "$files" = "*.RAW" ]` (same as `[ "${files[0]}" = "*.RAW" ]` in ksh/bash would have been wrong because there very well may be a file called `*.RAW`.