# How to delete remaining files of removed user?

Tags: find, users

I know deleting user with `userdel username` can cause information leakage and other security issues (as tutorial book says, administrator should delete user with `-r` option). But i tried it to see what happens. Now i have "unowned" directories left. I can delete them with `cd /home; rm -r username`. **Is there any quick way of doing it?**
The book says:

> The root user can find "unowned" files and directories by running: `find / -nouser -o -nogroup 2> /dev/null`

**How does it work?**

Comment: The above command just does a find of files that have no valid user or group owners. STDERR messages are sent to /dev/null

Comment: @fpmurphy1 that looks like an answer. People don't always look at the comments so you may want to post it below.

Comment: @fpmurphy1, thank you so much! I understand I/O redirection, but i don't understand those options: `-nouser -nogroup`. How do they work since files are not linked in system?

Comment: @Bratchley, it's not an answer. My main question is about deleting `home` directory. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, i solved it myself. With help of `find / -nouser -o -nogroup 2> /dev/null` you see all unlinked/unowned files on your system and you can delete every single file left on your system.

If you didn't use `-r` option with `userdel` command, you can do the following to get rid of all old user's files.

1. Delete removed user's `home` directory. `cd /home; rm -r username`
2. Find remaining files: `find / -nouser -o -nogroup 2> /dev/null`.
3. Delete every file in the output of previous command.

---

**Important edit**: Instead of these 3 steps, use:

```
find / -nouser -o -nogroup 2> /dev/null | xargs rm -fr
```

It removes every single output of `find` command with force (`-f`) and recursive (`-r`) options of `rm` command.

Quote from @Tim Pierce's answer on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62880/how-to-stop-the-find-command-after-first-match) question:

> `xarg` reads lines on standard input and turns them into command-line arguments, so you can effectively pipe data to the command line of another program.

---

**Edit #2**: According to @roaima, we need to use:

```
find / \( -nouser -o -nogroup \) -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

**Good luck!**

Comment: If you run that `find ... xargs` you could sooner or later end up deleting your entire filesystem, thanks to potentially "malicious" filenames. Use `find / \( -nouser -o -nogroup \) -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf` instead.

Comment: instead of `xargs` and `rm` use `-delete` as the last agument to find,  this was such a common problem they made it a built in.

Comment: I would do the bare find first, you may have other unowned files on your system that shoud belong to someone else instead of being deleted. especially of the user was working with shared files.

Comment: @roaima, thank you for comment, it works like a charm.

Comment: @Jasen, thank you, but that didn't work. Using `rm` is best in my mind, because it will delete folders too. 
About shared files: Shared files can't be "unowned". They will have owner = user, at least hostname.

Comment: @rzaaeeff the owner of a "shared" file could easily be the account for which you're trying to delete files.

Comment: @roaima, thank you, i didn't know it. Could you provide link to explain `-print0` and `-0` options?

Comment: @rzaaeeff `man find` and `man xargs`

Answer (score 0):

Or simpler, in the current directory:

```
sudo find . -nouser -nogroup | xargs rm -rf
```

Change `.` to the folder you want to check, `/` if it's for your entire filesystem.