# find exiting on 1st found and return code

Tags: find, bourne-shell

I would like to use `find` on a directory structure to exit if at least
one file exists with a target condition, because this will lead to a failure of the rest of a shell script.

Since this shell script is intended to run on big directory structures I would like to exit of it as soon as possible.

For example I would like to do:

```
find . -name "test" -prune
# if "test" file found, just exit immediately
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo error... >&2
    exit 2
fi
...continuation of shell script
```

But `-prune` is always evaluated to true.

What is the more efficient way to write a `find` expression to achieve
this kind of short circuit `find`?

I would like to use as standard as possible Bourne shell constructs
and avoid the use of any temporary file.

Comment: Do you want "just one" or "at least one" ?  By pruning, you'll get "at least one"; there could be 2,3,4 or more files that match in subdirectories.

Comment: At least one :).

Comment: it's unclear but i think you might want to run a find command akin to?:  find [directory] [conditions] -print -quit

Comment: Related: [How to stop the find command after first match?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62880)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `-prune` just stops recursion into subdirectories; it doesn't stop at the first found entry.  You probably want `-quit` with GNU or FreeBSD `find` or `-exit` with NetBSD `find`:

```
$ find . -name test 
./test
./Y/test

$ find . -name test -print -quit
./test
```

Instead of testing the return code of `find`, you can test the output

```
files=$(find . -name "test" -print -quit)

if [ -n "$files" ]
then
  echo "error... found $files" >&2
  exit 2
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
find . -name "test" |grep -m1 /test$
```