# limit find output AND avoid signal 13

Tags: shell, grep, find, signals, head

I have a directory with ~1M files and need to search for particular patterns. I know how to do it for all the files:

```
find /path/ -exec grep -H -m 1 'pattern' \{\} \;
```

The full output is not desired (too slow). Several first hits are OK, so I tried to limit number of the lines:

```
find /path/ -exec grep -H -m 1 'pattern' \{\} \; | head -n 5
```

This results in 5 lines followed by

```
find: `grep' terminated by signal 13
```

and `find` continues to work. This is well explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/554896/317607). I tried `quit` action:

```
find /path/ -exec grep -H -m 1 'pattern' \{\} \; -quit
```

This outputs only the first match.

Is it possible to limit find output with specific number of results (like providing an argument to `quit` similar to `head -n`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop the find command after first match?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62880/how-to-stop-the-find-command-after-first-match)

Comment: Not a duplicate, because `find` has a built-in option to stop after first match, but no means of counting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're already using GNU extensions (`-quit`, `-H`, `-m1`), you might as well use GNU `grep`'s `-r` option, together with `--line-buffered` so it outputs the matches as soon as they are found, so it's more likely to be killed of a SIGPIPE as soon as it writes the 6th line:

```
grep -rHm1 --line-buffered pattern /path | head -n 5
```

With `find`, you'd probably need to do something like:

```
find /path -type f -exec sh -c '
  grep -Hm1 --line-buffered pattern "$@"
  [ "$(kill -l "$?")" = PIPE ] && kill -s PIPE "$PPID"
  ' sh {} + | head -n 5
```

That is, wrap `grep` in `sh` (you still want to run as few `grep` invocations as possible, hence the `{} +`), and have `sh` kill its parent (`find`) when `grep` dies of a SIGPIPE.

Another approach could be to use `xargs` as an alternative to `-exec {} +`. `xargs` exits straight away when a command it spawns dies of a signal so in:

```
 find . -type f -print0 |
   xargs -r0 grep -Hm1 --line-buffered pattern |
   head -n 5
```

(`-r` and `-0` being  GNU extensions). As soon as `grep` writes to the broken pipe, both `grep` and `xargs` will exit and `find` will exit itself as well the next time it prints something after that. Running `find` under `stdbuf -oL` might make it happen sooner.

A POSIX version could be:

```
trap - PIPE # restore default SIGPIPE handler in case it was disabled
RE=pattern find /path -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    awk '\''
      $0 ~ ENVIRON["RE"] {
        print FILENAME ": " $0
        exit
      }'\'' < "$file"
    if [ "$(kill -l "$?")" = PIPE ]; then
      kill -s PIPE "$PPID"
      exit
    fi
  done' sh {} + | head -n 5
```

Very inefficient as it runs several commands for each file.

Comment: Thank you. I will use `grep -r` for this particular task, but it's good to know how to solve a general case. One note: `xargs` still prints error `xargs: grep: terminated by signal 13`, while `find` stops. I'd add `2> /dev/null` here.

Comment: The second approach may examine 100s or 1000s of files even though you're only interested in a couple because you are not limiting the lines that xargs will pass to grep. It also doesn't mask the SIGPIPE. Have a look at my suggestion.

Comment: @V13, you want to pass as many files to `grep` as possible, to run as few `grep` instances as possible. executing `grep` (which implies forking a process, loading the executables and libraries, do dynamic linking, initialise all libraries, internationalisation... and all the clean-up afterwards) has a formidable cost compared to `find` finding the files. With `--line-buffered`, `grep` should be killed early, so should not examine too many extra files once it has found 5 matching files.

Comment: @V13, also calling one `grep` for each file won't stop `find` finding extra files. A pipe (in a `find | xargs -n 1` approach) can hold thousands of files before getting full and causing `find` to block.

Comment: @Andrey, `2> /dev/null` would remove every error by grep and xargs, not just the `terminated  by signal 13` error by `xargs`.

Comment: Yes, I know, maybe it's just for my application I can ignore such errors. As a side note, `-r` is not supported by some implementations of `zgrep`, so only `find`-based solutions would work for compressed files.

Comment: @Andrey, `zgrep` is a generally a script that calls `gzip` and `grep` for each file anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A solution to avoid the errors could be this:

```
find / -type f -print0 \
  | xargs -0 -L 1 grep -H -m 1 --line-buffered 2>/dev/null \
  | head -10
```

In this example, xargs will stop once the command fails, so there'll be just one pipe error, which will be filtered by the stderr redirection.

Comment: Looks ok, and seems more elegant than mine.

Comment: The combination of `-0` with `-L` is not documented. In current versions of GNU `xargs` at least, `-L` does appear to work like `-n` with `-0` but I wouldn't count on it as that's not what it's meant to do without `-0`. Using `-n 1` would make more sense. In any  case, running one `grep` per file would generally be terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You `grep` one file at a time. With your `-quit`, you stop the find at the first successful grep.

[update] My first solution was to grep mutiple files at once:

```
find /path/ -type f -exec grep -H -m 1 'pattern' \{\} + -quit | head -n 5
```

(the magic is in the `+` at the end of the `-exec` sub-command. Added `-type f`. You may want to remove the `-H` option to `grep` if you are certain that /path/ contains several files)

The problem here, as reported by @StéphaneChazelas, is that the `-exec` command is executed asynchronously and returns always `true` => `find` quits at the first file.

If we want `find` to stop when `head` has finished, `find` must also receive the SIGPIPE that `grep` is getting (signal 13). That means that `find` must send something through the pipe.

Here is a quick-and-dirty hack, enhanced with Stéphane's suggestions:

```
find /path/ -type f -exec grep -H -m 1 --line-buffered 'pattern' {} + -printf '\r' | head -n 5
```

With `-printf '\r'` I force `find` to output a harmless character that will (hopefully) not alter the output of `grep`. Once `head` has stopped, `find` will receive a SIGPIPE and stop too.

[update2] I warned you that this is a dirty hack. Here is a better solution:

```
find /path/ -type f -exec grep --quiet 'pattern' {} ";" -print | head -n 5
```

Here, this is no longer `grep` that prints the filename, but `find` => no more "grep terminated by signal 13" and `find` stops with `head`. The problem is that matched lines are no longer printed by `grep`.

[update3] Finally, as suggested by @Andrey, the shamelessly hideous command below would solve this last issue:

```
find /path/ -type f \
    -exec grep --quiet 'pattern' {} \; \
    -printf '%p:' \
    -exec grep -h -m 1 'pattern' {} \; \
| head -n 5`
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for your suggestions. The problem here, as I understood it in the OP, is that `find` doesn't die because it never receives the SIGPIPE itself. Without `-quit` the only solution I see is to force `find` sending something to `stdout`. I'll amend my answer this way. Your opinion is welcome.

Comment: Another option is to use `grep -r` since we're already using several other GNU extensions here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `grep -r` is a far different solution that should be proposed independently, probably by you. (as for you `kill "$PPID"`, thanks, I'm no longer ashamed by my ugly hacks ;-)

Comment: Nice trick! A couple of thoughts: `grep -m 1` is essential in my case since each file might have thousands of matches; it's possible to emulate `grep -H` with `find /path/ -type f -printf '%p:' -exec grep -hm 1 'pattern' \{\} \; | head -n 5`.

Comment: @Andrey I did preserve the `-m1` flag, except in my last proposal where the `--quiet` option makes also `grep` stop at the first match. As for your command, I'm not sure this is what you want since you're `printf`ing every file before ensuring there is a grep. Maybe you meant `find /path/ -type f -exec grep -q 'pattern' {} \; -printf '%p:' -exec grep -hm 1 'pattern' \{\} \;`. That would do the trick indeed (in which case, tell me, I may add this to my answer)

Comment: Yes, you're right, just checked man for `-q`. The compound command `grep-printf-grep` works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

An alternate route for simpler cases could be just a here-string instead of a pipe. E.g -

```
find . -exec stat -c %y {} \; | head -n1
```

Would see the same issue as above. One easy method to consider -

```
head -n1 <<<$(find . -exec stat -c %y {} \;)
```

Comment: Doesn't that imply storing _the entire output of `find`_ in memory before even starting `head`?