# tail a log util keywords found or timeout

Tags: sed, tail, timeout, jenkins

I'm using a special way that can let me visit google. It is very different in the page now... So I can edit the question and comment the answers normally. I deleted more early discussions and go to the point.

I want to stop tailing and return 0 when keywords are found for the script to execute next commands. If keywords are not found after one minute, the whole script will be stopped to return an error code. I'm using `set -euxo pipefail` that is necessary.

```
timeout 1m tail -Fn 0 --pid=$(ps -ef | grep "sed /$keywords" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}') $log_file | sed "/$keywords/q"
```

The command above which I used before seamed ok when I tested. But in Jenkins, sometimes it returned "Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure" when the keywords were found.

I've found the reason when I restarted the program manually. It returned code 141. So I looked up the code, and found it is related with `tail -f` and pipe `|` in http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/sigpipe_handling.html.

---

I modified a command in other questions for my purpose. It seemed fine except that "tail -Fn 0 balabala.log" still remained in the background, which disappeared in several minutes. But it is nearest to the target.

```
{ sed /"$keywords"/q; kill -13 $!; } < <(exec timeout 1m tail -Fn 0 $log_file)
```

It's beyond my comprehension... I looked up the usages but still feel uncertain.

> 1. I changed `kill -s PIPE "$!"` to `kill -13 $!` to shorten the script.
> 2. I'm still confused about the usage of `{ } < <()`. They are like alien words to me...
> 3. Can `exec` be deleted? It seems different from not writting it.
> 4. What's wrong with the `tail` in the background? Is it dangerous if I start many programs in the same time?

Here is the log in Jenkins:

```
......
+ keywords='cloud-service-notice has been started successfully'
+ log_file=/data/jars/logs/info.cloud-service-notice.log
+ cd /data/jars/cloud-service-notice
+ nohup java -jar /data/jars/cloud-service-notice/cloud-service-notice.jar --spring.profiles.active=test
+ sed '/cloud-service-notice has been started successfully/q'
++ exec timeout 1m tail -Fn 0 /data/jars/logs/info.cloud-service-notice.log
2019-07-02 10:31:12,544 [main] INFO  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.prepareRefresh[588] - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@54a097cc: startup date [Tue Jul 02 10:31:12 CST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
......
2019-07-02 10:31:33,860 [main] INFO  c.enneagon.service.notice.NoticeApp.main[24] - cloud-service-notice has been started successfully
+ kill -13 20021
+ ssh web01 'cd /data/releases/cloud-service-notice/20190702-104108/.. &&' 'ls -1 | sort -r | awk '\''FNR > 20  {printf("rm -rf %s\n", $0);}'\'' | bash'
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The process 20021 was `timeout 1m tail -Fn 0 balabala.log`. After the script finished, the process 20023 `tail -Fn 0 balabala.log` remained, and disappeared a few minutes later.

```
[root@web01 scripts]# ps -ef | grep notice
root     20020     1 27 10:41 ?        00:01:07 java -jar /data/jars/cloud-service-notice/cloud-service-notice.jar --spring.profiles.active=test
root     20023     1  0 10:41 ?        00:00:00 tail -Fn 0 /data/jars/logs/info.cloud-service-notice.log
root     20461 18966  0 10:45 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto notice
```

I will answer my question with this command, but I'm not sure about it. I tested it in my local machines, and will put it in our production environment for further test.

---

After many tests, I finally changed the command to this:

```
{ sed /"$keywords"/q; kill $!; } < <(exec timeout 1m tail -Fn 0 $log_file)
```

`-13` just be removed. That is the reason why `tail -Fn 0 balabala.log` remained. I can answer the four questions above roughly:

> 1. `kill -15` is better because I added `timeout` in this command. `$!` is the pid of `timeout`. `tail -Fn 0 balabala.log` is a sub process here and using default number 15 can kill it.
> 2. It is just a process substitution and multiple processes using `{...}`. I can even ignore `kill` because after 1 minute `timeout` will kill itself in the background. So this command without `kill` is still acceptable: `sed /"$keywords"/q < <(exec timeout 1m tail -Fn 0 $log_file)`. In this situation, it will always return 0.
> 3. Better not. There will be two upper-level processes shown when the command is executed. But it will be all right after finishing.
> 4. The reason is in "1" above. `timeout` was killed, but `tail` was left.

Comment: After you finish tailing, you could `grep -A 1 $keyword | tail -n 1` so you get the line after your keyword. (or `tail -n 2` but you get the idea)

Comment: One reason could be that `tail` buffers its output, and when it gets the success line, it hasn't filled its buffer. It times out, `timeout` kills it, flushing the buffers, which go to `sed`, and you see the line in the output from `sed`. Try using `stdbuf` or `unbuffer`, etc. to disable buffering. Also, please don't use code formatting when quoting people.

Comment: @KuboMD, I think the OP meant that `tail` won't exit after it has written an extra line after `sed` has exited (after the keyword has been found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a command. Details are in the question.

```
{ sed /"$keywords"/q; kill $!; } < <(exec timeout 1m tail -Fn 0 $log_file)
```

`#!/bin/bash` and `set -euxo pipefail` are needed if in a script, which must be executed by `bash`, not `sh`, though linked to `bash` in CentOS.

Comment: I've tested this command for a week and it works well, so I'll mark this answer the right one that solved the problem. Thanks to @Stéphane Chazelas! I just added `timeout` in your command at the end of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416150/make-tail-f-exit-on-a-broken-pipe, and it touched my target! I'm still waiting for the answers of the doubts in my question. Hope somebody could answer them, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
sh -c 'echo "$$"; exec tail -f file' | (
  IFS= read -r pid
  timeout 60 sed "/$keyword/q"
  kill -s PIPE "$pid"
)
```

Unless you have enabled the `pipefail` option, that will exit with the exit status of `kill` which should be 0 unless `tail` has exited of its own (which shouldn't happen in practice).

With `pipefail`, that would exit with the exit status of `tail` killed by a SIGPIPE, (which most shells represent with a value of 141). You can always append a `|| true` to force a success exit status.

See also:

- [How to exit early on pipe close?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404272/how-to-exit-early-on-pipe-close?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Grep slow to exit after finding match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366797/grep-slow-to-exit-after-finding-match/366806#366806)
- [make tail -f exit on a broken pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416150/make-tail-f-exit-on-a-broken-pipe?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks, but it always returned 141, or 0 when added with `|| true`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening here is a race condition. `tail --pid=...` is depending on `tail` checking and realising that the tracked PID has died before it gets a SIGPIPE (usually signal no. 13, corresponding to the 128+13=141 exit status you got) from trying to write to a pipe broken by `sed` terminating. The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html#tail-invocation) only says "shortly after that process terminates, tail will also terminate", so the checking might not be frequent.

Anyway, if `tail` did get killed by SIGPIPE, that means (usually) `sed` has got the line you wanted and has quit, so that should *also* be a success condition for you. And I'd suggest treating it as exactly that, using an `if` block to protect against `set -e`, and explicitly checking the exit status:

```bsh
if timeout tail ... | sed ...; ret=$?; then
    : # do nothing, success
elif [ "$ret" != 141 ]  # not sigpipe, sed didn't quit, so failure
    exit "$ret"
fi
```

Aside: you said the script uses `#/bin/bash`. That should be `#!` with an exclamation mark, not just `#`. Without that the script would be run with sh, and that might be why your attempt to use process substitution (`<(...)` is *process*, not command, substitution) is a syntax error. Double check that.

I know you said you want a one liner, but a complicated one-liner is not always the best solution when it comes to maintainability. Use multiple lines if that means it's easier to document what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the keywords, so that it could reach one minute, to imitate a failure situation. But it got code 0.