# make tail -f exit on a broken pipe

Tags: sed, pipe, tail

I want to watch a file until a bit of text appears

I found this answer: [`tail -f` until text is seen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45941/tail-f-until-text-is-seen)

but when I tried it on ubuntu, it doesn't exit:

```
$ echo one > test.txt
$ echo two >> test.txt
$ echo three >> test.txt
$ echo four >> test.txt
$ cat test.txt | sed '/w/ q'
one
two
$
```

works as expected.  however when I try to tail the file

```
$ tail -f test.txt | sed '/w/ q'
one
two
```

it never exits.  tail does not stop even though the pipe is broken.

Does anybody know how to make `tail` exit when `sed` exits?

Comment: Similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366806/22565

Comment: I don't think either of those are similar to this question.  One is about writing your own program (in golang) that exits when the pipe is broken.  This question is specifically about `tail -f` and asking why something in a previous answer doesn't work.

Comment: The answers there explain why `tail -f` is not killed when `sed` exits, when the pipe is broken (because it doesn't write anything after) and how to work around it.

Comment: funny thing is what I am trying to do is an accepted answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45943/158192

Answer (score 10):

It's the same things as in:

- [How to exit early on pipe close?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404272)
- [Grep slow to exit after finding match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366797)
- [limit find output AND avoid signal 13](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/329778)

In:

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

Your shell happens to wait until `cmd1` terminates even after `cmd2` has already terminated. That's not the case of all shells. Some like the Bourne or Korn shell don't for instance.

When `cmd2` dies, the pipe on `cmd1`'s stdout becomes *broken*, but that doesn't terminate `cmd1` instantly.

`cmd1` will terminate the next time it tries to write to that pipe. It will then receive a SIGPIPE whose default action is to terminate the process.

With `cmd1` == `tail -f file` and `cmd2` == `sed /w/q`, `tail -f` will read the last 10 lines of the file and write them to stdout (the pipe), typically in one chunk unless the lines are really big and sit there waiting for more text to be appended to `file`.

`sed`, which runs concurrently, will wait for input on its stdin, read it, process it line by line and quit if there's a line that contains `w`.

As soon (or possibly with a one-line delay with some `sed` implementation) as it finds that line, it exits, but at that time, `tail` has already written to the pipe all it had to WRITE, so it won't receive a SIGPIPE unless some additional text is added later on to the file (at which point it will do the fatal `write()`).

If you wanted `cmd1` to terminate as soon as `cmd2` terminates, you'd need something to kill it once  `cmd2` terminates. Like with:

```
sh -c 'echo "$$"; exec tail -f test.txt' | {
  IFS= read pid
  sed /w/q
  kill -s PIPE "$pid"
}
```

Or with `bash`:

```
{ sed /w/q; kill -s PIPE "$!"; } < <(exec tail -f text.txt)
```

### 2020 Edit

As noted by @user414777, since version 8.28, the GNU implementation of `tail`, in follow modes, now not only polls for new data in the file(s) it monitors but also checks whether its stdout becomes a broken pipe and exits straight away then (or within one second if *inotify* is not used), making those work arounds above unnecessary.

However note that only GNU `tail` does this kind of processing, not any other implementation of `tail` (AFAIK), and not any other utility (even the GNU implementations).

So, while:

```
tail -f file | head -n1
```

Will exit after one line,

```
tail -f file | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' | head -n1
```

for instance will not necessarily as `tr` will not monitor whether its stdout becomes a broken pipe, and so will only die if it *writes* something there after the pipe has broken as usual (and it's only at that point that GNU `tail -f` will exit).

Comment: +1! very useful for tailing a file until a message happens (such as waiting for a deploy to finish): `{ awk '{print $0};/has finished in/{exit}' ; kill -s PIPE "$!" ; } < <(exec tail -f /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out)`

Comment: Note that `mawk` buffers output by default. If you are on debian/ubuntu, you want to either use `gawk` or pass the `-Winteractive` flag to `mawk` for this trick to work. See https://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html

Comment: @JonasDahlbæk all awk implementations  buffer their output when it doesn't go to a terminal. What's unique to mawk is that it buffers its input (accumulates a block full before starting to process it)

Comment: You are right, of course.

Comment: See the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/616346/414777) about the special thing GNU tail does so that the `tail -f | sed /pat/q` (sometimes) works.

Comment: Thanks @user414777, I've now added a section about it.