# Programmatically closing pipeline / exiting

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, fifo

I have a pipeline like so:

```
  tail -n0 -f  "${my_input}" | ql_receiver_lock_holder | while read line; do
   echo "$line" >> "${my_output}";
   # xxx: how can I programmatically close the pipeline at this juncture?
  done & disown;
```

my question: is there a way to programmatically close the pipeline where it says xxx? I could probably just call `exit 0;` but I am wondering if there is a way to close the current pipeline somehow.

Comment: What effect do you want to achieve here? Read a single line of input? If so, why use `while` at all?  `ql_receiver_lock_holder | (read line; echo ...) & disown` would work just as well for that. Or do you want to end the loop? In which case a simple `break` would do.

Comment: For me this sound like you want to `break` out of the loop, but it is really difficult to understand what you want to archive.

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
tail -n0 -f -- "$my_input" |
  ql_receiver_lock_holder |
  sed /xxx/q > "$my_output"
```

- `sed` would exit after reading the first line containing `xxx`.
- `ql_receiver_lock_holder` would then exit (killed by a SIGPIPE) upon the first write it does to stdout (the now broken pipe) after that.
- Likewise, `tail` would exit upon the first write it does after that.

If you want `ql_receiver_lock_holder` and `tail` to exit as soon as `sed` exits without waiting for their next write to stdout, you can use approaches described at

- [make tail -f exit on a broken pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416150)

Note that [this kind of `while read` loop is not the right way to process text in shells](/a/169765). At the very least, you'd need something like:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
  case $line in
    (*xxx*) break
  esac
done
```

to replace the `sed /xxx/q` but which would be terribly inefficient except for very small input.