# How to find all git repositories within given folders (fast)

Tags: find, git

Naive approach is `find dir1 dir2 dir3 -type d -name .git | xargs -I {} dirname {}`
, but it's too slow for me, because I have a lot deep folder structures inside git repositories (at least I think that this is the reason). I've read about that I can use `prune` to prevent find to recurse into directories once it found something, but there's two things. I'm not sure how this works (I mean I don't understand what `prune` does although I've read man page) and the second it wouldn't work in my case, because it would prevent `find` to recurse into `.git` folder but not into all other folders.

So what I actually need is:

for all subdirectories check if they contain a `.git` folder and if it is then stop searching in this filesystem branch and report result. It would be perfect if this would also exclude any hidden directories from search.

Comment: `getpof .git` is what I use. https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/filesys/getpof.c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981716/how-to-quickly-find-all-git-repos-under-a-directory

Comment: You can use `-maxdepth` if you know a good value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you'd want to crawl directory trees for directories that contain a `.git` entry and stop searching further down those (assuming you don't have further git repos inside git repos).

The problem is that with standard `find`, doing this kind of check (that a directory contains a `.git` entry) involves spawning a process that executes a `test` utility using the `-exec` predicate, which is going to be less efficient than listing the content of a few directories.

An exception would be if you use the `find` builtin of the `bosh` shell (a POSIXified fork of the Bourne shell developed by [@schily](/users/120884)) which has a `-call` predicate  to evaluate code in the shell without having to spawn a new sh interpreter:

```
#! /path/to/bosh -
find . -name '.?*' -prune -o \
  -type d -call '[ -e "$1/.git" ]' {} \; -prune -print
```

Or use `perl`'s `File::Find`:

```
perl -MFile::Find -le '
  sub wanted {
    if (/^\../) {$File::Find::prune = 1; return}
    if (-d && -e "$_/.git") {
       print $File::Find::name; $File::Find::prune = 1
    }
  }; find \&wanted, @ARGV' .
```

Longer, but faster than `zsh`'s `printf '%s\n' **/.git(:h)` (which descends into all non-hidden directories), or GNU `find`'s `find . -name '.?*' -prune -o -type d -exec test -e '{}/.git' \; -prune -print` which runs one `test` command in a new process for each non-hidden directory.

**2022 edit**. The `find` applet from recent versions of busybox is able to run its `[` or `test` applet without having to fork a process and reexecute itself inside, so, even though it's still not as fast as the bosh or perl approaches:

```
busybox find . -type d -exec [ -e '{}/.git' ] ';' -prune -print
```

In my test is several orders of magnitude faster than the GNU `find` equivalent (on a local sample containing a mix of git / cvs / svn repositories with over 100000 directories in total, I get 0.25s for bosh, 0.3s for perl 0.7s for busybox `find`, 36s for GNU `find`, 2s for GNU `find . -name .git -printf '%h\n'` (giving a different result as it also finds `.git` files in subdirs of git repositories)).

Comment: Note that `.git` can be a file as well - via `git worktree`

Comment: Thanks @StevenPenny, I wasn't aware of that. I've now changed the `-d`s to `-e`.

Answer (score 16):

Okay, I still don't totally sure how this works, but I've tested it and it works.

```
.
├── a
│   ├── .git
│   └── a
│       └── .git
└── b
    └── .git

6 directories, 0 files

% find . -type d -exec test -e '{}/.git' ';' -print -prune
./a
./b
```

I'm looking forward into making the same faster.

Comment: This of `-prune` this way: You start at the root of a tree you move down it and when a certain condition applies you cut of a whole subtree (like real "pruning"), so you won't look at any more nodes in this subtree.

Comment: @phk oh, thanks. I seem to grasp it now. We searching directories `-type d` for which condition `test -e ...` is true and if it's true we execute actions `-print -prune` which means print it and cut subtree, right?

Comment: Yes, we cut the subtree of which it is the root.

Comment: Quick one to use your solution to "update" all git repos:
`find . -type d -exec test -e '{}/.git' \; -print -prune | parallel cd "{}" \&\& git pull --rebase`
GNU `parallel` is a very handy replacement for `xargs`

Comment: you will not get sub-modules, which are also git repos.
You might want to fetch them by recursively fetching sub-modules, once you have the root-repos list returned by this command.

Answer (score 3):

If you use locate, you could find directories with:

```
locate .git | grep "/.git$"
```

Result list is fast and further processing is easy, too.

Comment: `locate '*/.git'` should be enough.

Comment: best idea, fastest result ! Use locate as much as possible, excepted when your queries expect fresh and volatile data.

Answer (score 2):

### Possible Solution

For GNU `find` and other implementations that support `-execdir`:

```sh
find dir1 dir2 dir3 -type d -execdir test -d '.git' \; -print -prune
```

(see the comments)

### Previously discussed stuff

#### Solution if pruning below `.git` is enough

```sh
find dir1 dir2 dir3 -type d -path '*/.git' -print -prune | xargs -I {} dirname {}
```

If `-printf '%h'` is supported (as in the case of GNU's `find`) we don't need `dirname`:

```sh
find dir1 dir2 dir3 -type d -path '*/.git' -printf '%h\n' -prune
```

Once it comes across a folder `.git` in the current path it will output it and then stop looking further down the subtree.

#### Solution if the whole folder tree should be pruned once a `.git` is found

Using `-quit` if your `find` supports it:

```sh
for d in dir1 dir2 dir3; do
  find "$d" -type d -name .git -print -quit
done | xargs -I {} dirname {}
```

(According to [this detailed post by Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62883/117599) `-quit` is supported in GNU's and FreeBSD's `find` and in NetBSD as `-exit`.)

Again with `-printf '%h'` if supported:

```sh
for d in dir1 dir2 dir3; do
  find "$d" -type d -name .git -printf '%h\n' -quit
done
```

#### Solution for pruning at the same level as where the `.git` folder is

See the **"Possible Solution"** part for the current solution for this particular problem.

(Oh and obviously the solutions using `xargs` assume there are no newlines in the paths, otherwise you would need null-byte magic.)

Comment: if `dir1` contains two directories `dirx` and `diry` that each contain a `.git` directory, this only reports  `dirx/.git`

Comment: @iruvar Ah OK, I misunderstood you in that case, I will try to redo the solution then.

Comment: the issue with your new solution is this if `dir1/.git` exists, it still descends `dir1/dirx`, which, based on my reading of OP's requirement, is not desired

Comment: @iruvar OK, added that as well. Any other ideas about what OP could have meant? ;-)

Comment: @iruvar exactly

Comment: @user1685095 OK, then the last solution is for you. I will still leave the others there, might be useful for someone else.

Comment: @phk well... first of all using `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1...` to check if there is a `.git` folder is very inefficient. Second this is just a for loop without any parallelization, and I've said I need this to be fast. And the last one - this can be done with just one line. `find d1 d2 d3 -type d -exec test -e '{}/.git' ';' -print -prune`, but I'm not sure it's fast enough for me. Is there a way to make -exec in parallel, because it seems to be performance bottleneck.

Comment: @user1685095 You can use `xargs -P` if your implementation has it or alternatively one of the tools called `parallel` (one is AFAIK Python code though). But in a sense I'm not sure it would be faster this way, because I don't think CPU is much of a bottleneck here.

Comment: @phk I know about xargs and parallel, the problem is that if I understand right exec not only executes the command on search results, but also affects `-prune`. I mean the reason `find` doesn't descend deeper is because `test -e` returned `true`. And xargs can't do that.

Comment: @phk CPU isn't the bottleneck, but disk IO and kernel calls is. And if it can be done in parallel that would speed things right?

Comment: @user1685095 Not sure, would have to benchmark it. BTW, what about the latest solution?

Comment: @phk well, I've already told you, it's inefficient and not nice.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `ls -d */.git` and then strip the `.git` at the end.

This wont look for subfolders.

Comment: How would the stripping part work in practice, how would the command like like?

Comment: `ls -d */.git | sed "s/\/\.git$//"`. You can even print 1 folder per line by adding `-1` to `ls`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
find ~/GIT-REPOSITORIES \( -exec test -d '{}'/.git \; \) -print -prune
```

`time` this, to see the difference with and without `-prune`.

This is based on a solution in the `man find`. You can edit out the `CVS` and `svn` if not required. man page content follows

```bsh
find repo/ \( -exec test -d '{}'/.svn \; -or \
       -exec test -d {}/.git \; -or -exec test -d {}/CVS \; \) \
       -print -prune
```

Given the following directory of projects and their associated SCM administrative directories, perform an efficient search for the projects' roots:

```
repo/project1/CVS
repo/gnu/project2/.svn
repo/gnu/project3/.svn
repo/gnu/project3/src/.svn
repo/project4/.git
```

In  this  example, `-prune` prevents unnecessary descent
into directories that have already been discovered
(for example, we  do  not  search `project3/src`,
because we already found `project3/.svn`),
but ensures sibling directories (`project2` and `project3`)
are found.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution to **show all repos** and **their current branches**:

```
for d in `find . -name "HEAD" -prune | grep "git/HEAD" | sort`; do echo $d | sed 's/\.git\/HEAD//'; cat $d; echo; done
```

Result:

```
path1
ref: current_brach_of_repo

path2
ref: current_brach_of_repo

path3
ref: current_brach_of_repo
```

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/80216)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).