# Print all subdirectories in the current directory that do not contain a .git

Tags: bash, find, git, test, exec

I'm trying to write a bash line that will look at all the subdirectories in my current folder and tell me if any do NOT contain a ".git". Pseudo:

```
for subdir in currentdir
  if .git does not exist
    print subdir
```

Here's the one-liner I'm trying, which isn't working and seems to print all the subdirectories:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir $SHELL -c '[ ! -d ".git" ] && echo "not git repo:" {}' $SHELL -c '{}' ';'
```

I've found some solutions that let me print all subdirectories that HAVE a .git, like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333862/how-to-find-all-git-repositories-within-given-folders-fast) -- I'm trying to do the opposite.

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the `-execdir` command looks wonky (2x `$SHELL -c`?):

```
$SHELL -c '[ ! -d ".git" ] && echo "not git repo:" {}' $SHELL -c '{}' ';'
```

Also, `-execdir` runs the command in the directory containing the matched entity, (so the parent directory of the directory that it is checking right now), which is `.` for all subdirectories. The test is run in the wrong directory. And:

- You shouldn't reuse `{}` in `exec`/`-execdir` commands.
- There's no reason to use `$SHELL`. That's the user's login shell, and it doesn't have any special significance for usage in scripts and such. Just use `sh`, or `bash` or `ksh` if those are your shells of choice, directly.

This might work:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '! [ -d "$1/.git" ] && echo "not git repo: $1"' _ {} \;
```

The `-exec` command checks for the existence of `.git` in the argument passed in, which is each subdirectory in turn. You might also want to use `-mindepth 1` to exclude the current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '! [ -d "$1/.git" ] && echo "not git repo: $1"' _ {} \;
```

Or, just using bash, enabling `dotglob` to match hidden directories:

```
(shopt -s dotglob; for d in ./*/; do [[ -d $d/.git ]] || echo "not git repo: $d"; done)
```

Comment: Thank you! I found the `$SHELL` bit (somewhere...) as a solution to "you can't do `test` using `exec`" but as these answers prove, that appears to have been incorrect. Can you explain why I shouldn't reuse `{}` in `exec`/`execdir`?

Comment: It may not work correctly depending on the version of `find`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12965441/2072269

Answer (score 2):

[muru’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525535/86440) explains what’s wrong with your approach. The answers to [the question you referred to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333862/86440) suggest a simpler approach with no shell involved:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec test '!' -e '{}/.git' ';' -printf "not git repo: %p\n"
```

(assuming your `find` supports `-printf`), or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec test '!' -e '{}/.git' ';' -print
```

This negates the test run using `-exec test` to get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you! The negated test is a much simpler approach as well.