# How to stop the find command after second match?

Tags: linux, find

How to make `find` command, that will show only first two matches and then end, something similiar to [How to stop the find command after first match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62880/how-to-stop-the-find-command-after-first-match) just version for two records.

Comment: I think nothing is wrong with this question to get down-vote (at least in my opinion), if no, please leave comment where it's wrong question.

Comment: In particular nothing wrong without an explanatory comment.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `1` to `2` in your linked answer.

```
find . ... -print | head -n 2
```

---

Note that this *does* assume that the filenames are sane, i.e. they do not contain newlines.  Therefore it is not the most appropriate for a scripted solution.  (See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943) for more details.)  It's still by far the most suitable approach for quick interactive use.

Also note that on a system with a great many files, this will be faster than a `-exec sh -c 'echo "$1"; echo "$2"' _ {} +` approach, because the `find` process will receive SIGPIPE when it tries to write more filenames after `head` has completed, and then `find` will end.

Not to mention that the `-exec` command may print a LOT more than 2 results if there are sufficiently many results.  For example, `find / -exec sh -c 'echo "$1"; echo "$2"' _ {} +` will not exit for a very long time, and will print two files out of every ARG_MAX results rather than two files total.

Comment: And is there any option, to pick only second reasult from this query?

Comment: Several ways.  `find [...] | head -n2 | tail -n1`; `find [...] | sed -n '2p'`; `find [...] | awk 'NR==2 { print }'`, amongst myriad others.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` with invoking `sh`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$1" "$2"; done' _ {} +
```

This will expand all files since of using `+` terminator of `-exec` then we are just printing first and second arguments which are first and second files `find` found.

---

Or use as following which where you can specify after how many files found (maybe not 2 files, 100 files! then at above you should specify all 100 files!) *exit* the command (actually shell send `exit` command and cause `find` exit its running process).

```sh
find -type f -exec sh -c '
    for file; do echo "$file"; c=$((c+1)); [ $c = 2 ] && exit; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: Note that if there are HUGE numbers of results (in excess of ARG_MAX for the system), this command may also operate on another file besides the one intended.