# Improving performance of Script Using find and exec

Tags: scripting, find, date, performance, compression

I have a script that iterates through a given directory and automatically compresses those that do not contain at least one file used in less than 30 days. Now, I am wondering if I could improve performance by using find together with exec. I tried something, but it is not working. Do you have any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/bash
# find all the directories
dirs=`find . -type d`
# iterate every file in every directory
for dir in $dirs
do
        n="totar"
        # search all the file in the directory
        files=`find $dir -type f -atime -30`
        for file in $files
        do
                n="keepasis"
        done
        if [ $n == "totar" ]; then
                tar -zcvf $dir.tgz $dir
                rm -r $dir
        fi
done
```

My idea was to replace the second for loop with something like:

```
find $dir -type f -atime -30 -exec n="keepasis" {} \;
```

Comment: You realise that this would try to archive the topmost directory and delete it (with all subdirectories) if it happens to contain a file (anywhere below) that has been recently accessed? Is this what you want?  What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: The idea is that I compress those directories, that I have not been using for more than 30 days. I used rm to delete the directory "dublicate" once I compressed it. I realize though that this could happen to my topmost directory if I never used a file inside. Which I don't desire. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a variable in `find`'s `-exec` action this will not be visible.

The fact that `find` has found a file and printed its name is sufficient to decide that you don't want to archive the directory. So you don't need the `for file in $files` loop, instead check that `$files` is not empty.

If your `find` command supports the `-quit` action you can use this to stop after the first match. (see [How to stop the find command after first match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62880/how-to-stop-the-find-command-after-first-match))

Instead of putting the output of the first `find` into a variable and using a for loop with word splitting you should better read `find`'s output lime by line.

```
#!/bin/bash
# find all the directories
# -mindepth 1 prevents "find" from printing "."
find . -mindepth 1 -type d | while read -r dir
do
    # a subdirectory might no longer exist if a parent has been archived before
    if [ -d "$dir" ]
    then
        # search any new file in the directory
        newfilefound=`find $dir -type f -atime -30 -print -quit`

        if [ -z "$newfilefound" ]
        then
            tar -zcvf $dir.tgz $dir
            rm -r $dir
        fi
   fi
done
```

If you are using bash you can improve the first `find` to correctly handle more directory names with special characters: `find . -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do`...

There is still a performance issue:

If a directory contains a new file somewhere in a subdirectory you don't remove it. Later you will get all subdirectory names down to the one with this file. In this case you will use `find` several times to find the same new file.

The only solution that comes to my mind is to use two `find`, some post-processing and one `fgrep`:

1. Let one `find` print the names of all new files, process the output by removing the file names, printing all the parent directories as separate lines and removing duplicates and putting the list into a file NEWDIRS.
2. With a second `find` print all directory names to a second file ALLDIRS.
3. Use `fgrep` to find all lines from ALLDIRS that don't match a line in NEWDIRS.

You should check that the `tar` command was successful before removing the directory.

Comment: Thank you Bobo. I really appreciate your answer and great explanation!

Comment: This, like the code in the question, would try to archive the current directory if any file anywhere below it has been recently accessed.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Maybe there is a bug I don't currently see. My understanding is that `-atime -30 -print` will print a file name when the file has an access time of less than 30 days ago. `if [ -z "$newfilefound" ]` will execute the archiving commands if the output of `find` is empty, i.e. if no file matching the condition was found. Is there something wrong? Please explain.

Comment: I got my logic back to front. The code would try to archive and delete the top-most directory if no recently accessed file was found anywhere below it.  The name of the archive in that case, would be `..tgz`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I will add `-mindepth 1` to the first `find` to prevent it from printing `.`.